# Java : Store and retrieving image in db4o

Tags: java, db4o

I want to store and retrieving image in db4o with java
I have read some topic about store image in db4o but i can not do
I have db ;

```
class WaterFish {
     String fishname;
      String biology;
     String information;
     Fish_Image image ;

      }
class Fish_Image {
     Blod image;
     public Fish_Image(Blod image){
        this.image = image;
    }
    public Blod getFishImage(){
       return image;
    }
```

So, how I can store and retrieving image with structure like that. Give me some detail example with code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Blobs` to store images in object container. See the documentation for using [**Blobs**](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/type_handling/blobs.htm).

[Db4o Blob Implementation](http://community.versant.com/Documentation/Reference/db4o-8.0/java/reference/Content/implementation_strategies/type_handling/blobs/db4o_blob_implementation.htm) gives you an example. Hope you are using

Comment: code in 2 site you give me
have 2 folder : blods/in and blods/out
inFolder ( "blobs\in\") is used as a location of existing files, which are to be stored into db4o, and outFolder ( "blobs\out\") will be the place for images, retrieved from the database.
when i run my program, images be stored onto db40 but it copy images on blods folder not blods/out folder
i dont know why?
and i dont want my program cropy images in blods/in folder
and how i solve this problem ?